# Implement Array Random Shuffle

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, random, generator, pseudocode

### Prelude

I am writing a grid-based random-map generator.
Currently, I want to populate a 2D array with a variety of tiles.

---

### Problem

*In the parenthesis is a more concrete example.*

Here is what you are given:

- 2D array and its dimensions. (i.e. 3x4 grid)
- `Integer Random(Range)` (i.e. Range: 0-11, Output: integer from 0-11)

  - You do **NOT** have a function that randomly sorts an array, **unless you implement it yourself**.
- Number of each type of tile (i.e. Desert: 2, Lake: 4, Forrest: 6)

How do I populate this array with the given tiles?

---

### Example

3x4 map; 6 **F**orrest; 4 **L**ake; 2 **D**esert...

```
F F L
L D F
D F F
L F L
```

---

### Attempt

I do have my own implementation, however its Big-O is... infinity, I think. `:)`

Of course, the chances that it will never finish are slim; however, this is part of a video game and I don't want to keep the player waiting.

---

### Postscript

I don't really care what language that it is implemented in; pseudo-code will be satisfactory.

Comment: So you need to populate each array index with one of these tiles?

Comment: Yes. I'll add an example of what it ought to more-less look like.

Answer (score 0):

This could one of the way to do it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
//Map which keeps the value for each key (2,4,6) 
map<int,char> alphabet;
void initMap()
{
alphabet[2] = 'D';
alphabet[4] = 'L';
alphabet[6] = 'F';
} 


int main()
{
   char a[3][4];
   // counter variables to keep track of d,f and l
   int temp,d=0,f=0,l=0;
   initMap();

   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
      for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
      {
        //This determines if the generated random number is already entered in the grid. If no than breaks out. If yes than again a new random number is generated and process is iterated untill the new number is found to enter
        while(1)
        {
            temp = rand()%4;
            if(temp==0)
            {
                temp = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = temp*2;
            }

            if(temp ==2 && d<2)
            {
                d++;
                break;
            }
            else if(temp ==4 && l<4)
            {
                l++;
                break;
            }
            else if(temp ==6 && f<6)
            {
                f++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        //char value for the number temp is assigned from the alphabet map
       a[i][j]  = alphabet.at(temp);
       cout<<a[i][j]<<"  ";
     }
   cout<<endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

output:

```
D  F  L  D
L  L  L  F
F  F  F  F
```

You can map the alphabet according the number when entering the value or accessing the value from array.

Comment: So will this always result in the same tiles (eg: 6 Forrest; 4 Lake; 2 Desert) every time (but in different order)?

Comment: You can try and run. Will create different map everytime you run the code consisting of the tiles you said in the question.

Comment: I updated the code even more I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: No, this still does not always end up with 2 D, 4 L, and 6 F (see your output). You have 7 D, 4 L, and 1 F. It **must** have  2 D, 4 L, and 6 F, however the order does not matter.

Comment: Sorry that was not clear to me. I corrected the code please check. I hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Do you mind briefly commenting your code so I can get an idea of what each component does?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116948/discussion-between-denis-and-sir-jony-not-ive).

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure the inputs are correct (e.g. total count of tiles equals
   the count of slots in the grid)
2. put all give tiles into a queue Q, whose length is n(in your
   example, n=12)
3. intialize a result array R[p], p is intialized as 0
4. get k=random(1->n), deque Q[k] into R[p], p++
5. repeat step 4 until p goes to n

Things can be much more easier if you use a language that has built-in sort functions:

1. verify input
2. put given tiles into an one demension array A[n]
3. sort A[n] randomly

Code in C#:

```
    int m = 3;
    int n = 4;  //m*n grid

    int forrests = 6;
    int lakes = 4;
    int deserts = 2;

    if (m * n != forrests + lakes + deserts)
    {
        //invalid input!
    }

    char[] tiles = new char[m * n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m * n; i++)
    {
        if (i < forrests)
        {
            tiles[i] = 'F';
        }
        else if (i < forrests + lakes)
        {
            tiles[i] = 'L';
        }
        else
        {
            tiles[i] = 'D';
        }
    }

    //preparation completed, now tiles[] looks like 
    //F,F,F,F,F,F,L,L,L,L,D,D

    char[] output = tiles.OrderBy(t => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
    //output is randomly sorted from tiles

    //if you really need a two-demension array
    char[][] map = new char[n][];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        map[i] = output.Skip(m * i).Take(m).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: The library I am using does not include `.OrderBy(t => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray()`. Can it be manually implemented easily?